# How to list all files in a Windows SMB network share

Tags: windows, linux, samba, find, smb

Given a single SMB network share (for example, `\\server\\SHARED_FOLDER`), I want to recursively list all the files, including those in the subdirectories (like `find(1)`).

I would prefer to do it in Linux, but I also accept Windows answers.

Comment: .. assuming *without mounting* it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use:

```
sudo smbmount //server/SHARED_FOLDER /local/folder
cd /local/folder
ls -R
```

Obviously, add your preferred `ls` flags into the command (so, for me, I would use `ls -lahR`, but that's a personal preference).

Answer (score 17):

Try the command: `smbclient //HOST/PATH -c 'recurse;ls'  PASS -U USER`

Comment: smbclient //192.168.1.10/smb/tmp -c 'recurse;ls'

Comment: tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_NAME